# I've lost a pen drive but I printed off a word document from it a few days... Can I recover a temp version from Word or Windows?

Tags: microsoft-word, usb-storage

Is there a way to recover documents that have been printed off a pen drive but the pen drive has been lost?

I've check the print and there is no file, would word or windows keep a temp copy of a document?

Using Office 2007 and WinXp.

Hope someone gets what I'm saying.

Comment: If you had that file on hdd at some point of time, you can try recovering it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not. Word keeps the autosave files in a temporary folder, but it gets deleted when you shutdown the computer. The print spool service also has a temporary folder is uses for spooled files, but those get deleted immediately after printing.

If you haven't restarted your computer, you could try looking in the autosave folder.

And if the file is really, really important, you could run an undelete utility such as [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec). It can scan for files based on their type and extension; have it search for Word files. Depending on your hard drive size, this will take hours to days to complete.

Here's hoping you find your pen drive (or backed up the file elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks dymutaos, ended up using an online OCR to get a soft copy of the document.